# How to correctly calculate the current market cap

Tags: market-capitalization, split

I'm having a trouble with the question which may seem very easy at a first sight. Basically, to calculate a market cap we just need to take the current price and multiply it by the number of outstanding shares from balance sheet. Unfortunately, sometimes it is not so easy.

For example, I need to calculate a market cap for CPRT. However, recently such situation happen with them: fiscal period has ended, x2 stock split has happened, report for the previous fiscal period issued. In the latest report they declared not the number of outstanding shares for that period but actually for the upcoming when the split happened. I tried to obtain calculated cap from some data source (like FMP) but data is broken there too (capitalisation rapidly increases/decreases x2 times in a couple of weeks due to this report/split trick).

Also I can't just take the last capitalization value and adjust it to splits because of the flow between outstanding/treasury stocks.

I had an idea to calculate capitalization this way: if split happens then I adjust the number of outstanding shares to the split ratio UNTIL the next filling date. Such method will work with the current CPRT situation but I'm concerned that other companies may do vice versa: fiscal period finished, split happens, report published with outstanding shares num for the finished period. Then I'm getting a broken data again.

How can I correctly handle the situation with splits/reports and capitalization calculation?

Comment: The companies make an announcement before they split their stock as to the ratios and timing. They will also announce the number of outstanding shares in their quarterly reports. You either need to gain access a good quality financial fundamental data provider or follow the announcements by the companies you are interested in closely and use the information in those announcements as per necessary.